# How to fix unexpected end of json error when i run JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, ejs, fabricjs

I'm working on a document verification project.
my code works when the document exists or when the logged person issued the document.
but it fails and returns an "unexpected end of JSON" error when the document is not issued by the logged person(for example for new user).
the error is returned when I used JSON.parse(documents) on Ejs.
how can I catch the error with try-catch or any other means in EJS?
here is the  result of code when the document found(expected output)

```
<% console.log('fit', JSON.parse(documents, null, '\t')) %>

Output
fit [ { Key: 'DOCUMENT0', Record: { name: 'bachelor of science degree', url: 'https://bitcoin.org/ggg.pdf', issuedBy: 'sol123', dateOfIssuance: '12:18 PM, 25 September, 2021', hashedDoc: 'dac729a8acf4b8a88f73f5bd84206c34e01e0992efa251b772f68696e2c2539c9ed0090e73ef6b87dc24e3177c6fd5341c3e9e24ef14267ce07ab9428aeed897', docType: 'Whitepaper' } } ]
```

The problem is when the document is not found(for example, if the user is new and not yet issued document);

```
SyntaxError: /home/verification/fabcar/javascript/views/pages/dashboard.ejs:15
    13|     <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    14| 
 >> 15|     <% JSON.parse(documents).forEach(document => { %>
    16|         <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="<%= document.Key %>" data-bs-toggle="tab"
    17|           href="#list-<%= document.Key %>" role="tab" aria-controls="list-<%= document.Key %>" style="min-width: 200px;"><%= document.Key %></a>
    18|     <% }) %>

Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>
```

what I want is,
how can I display the `NO DOCUMENT ISSUED` message on EJS  when there is no document issued by the user. please I need your help I'm new to javaScript and ejs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **try catch**

```
try {

  let user = JSON.parse(json); 

} catch (err) {
  
  alert( "user is new and not yet issued document" );
  console.log( err.name );
  console.log( err.message );
}
```

by doing so you can verify each error and respond accordingly.

or else use validation **true or false function** like following and continue accordingly

```
function isValidJSON(text) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(text);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Updated for the question : How to create try catch in ejs

here is example of try catch

```
<%

function isValidJSON(text) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(text);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
var json1 = '{"item" : {"item2" : "item Data"}}';
var json2 = '{"item" : {"item2" : "item Data}}';

%>



pasing json 
<% if(isValidJSON(json1))  { %>
<p>Valid jsonr!</p>
<% } else { %>
<p>Invalid Json!</p>

<% } %>

pasing json 
<% if(isValidJSON(json2))  { %>
<p>Valid jsonr!</p>
<% } else { %>
<p>Invalid Json!</p>

<% } %>
```

you can see the json1 is valid and json2 is invalid.

Comment: thank you for your answer c, but how can i  create try  catch in ejs  or function in ejs?

Comment: it is java script not C, and updated code ejs code

Comment: thank you  Kumara.